# Which Java SE versions work with android studio 3.1?

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle

Which Java SE version works with android studio 3.1?

I recently installed Java SE 10 on Windows 10, but android studio always displays Gradle sync failed message with the following error:

```
Could not determine Java version using executable C:\program Files\java\jdk-10\bin\java.exe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum possible version for Android Studio 3.1 is Java 8. Also, some of the features of Java 8 are unavailable for lower API versions. For example, my minimum API version is 16 and if I try to use `stream`, I get errors because these features are available only for API 24 and higher. You can use lambda expressions, method references however etc.
To know more, visit this [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html)

Comment: Can you tell me which version of Java 8 should I need to install? Cause there are many version of Java 8 available.And  I already tried "Java 8u162" but this version gives Internet Explorer error. so please suggest me the java 8 version which doesn't have bug.