# Changing JDK in Android Studio, Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, ubuntu-16.04, java-10

I have a problem changing the default JDK for Android Studio on Ubuntu OS. The default version is located at `/home/USER/Documents/android-studio/jre`, which is Java 1.7, but I wanna use the Java 10.0.1 that I have installed but I simply can't find the path to the newer JDK (Android Studio is saying "Please choose a valid JDK directory"). I have used this tutorial to install new java: [How to Install JDK 10 (on Windows, Mac OS & Ubuntu) and Get Started with Java Programming](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html)

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788102/which-java-se-versions-work-with-android-studio-3-1 it wont work even if you do set to 10

Answer (score 1):

$ echo $JAVA_HOME

Copy the path displayed in terminal

Android studio File -> Project Structure -> Paste the copied path

more info

https://askubuntu.com/questions/467870/how-to-set-the-jdk-for-android-studio