# gradle wrapper failed, "could not determine java version from 11.0.1" for android app

Tags: java, android, gradle, wrapper, spotify

I am trying to use this spotify API wrapper(https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android) but when I run
    ./gradlew assemble
I get the following error:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info 
or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: You're using Java 11 to run Gradle, but that library uses Gradle 2.4 for the wrapper which isn't compatible with Java 11.

Comment: how should I go about fixing this? downgrade java or gradle. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Considering that library seems geared towards Android, and that you have this question tagged with `android`, I would think you should be using Java 8. However, I'm not familiar with Android nor the tools necessary to develop for it. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456107/does-android-support-java-11