# Android Studio seems to be stuck at Java 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, java-11

I'm trying to update the jdk of an AndroidStudio-App to the newest possible version (From what I've read `jdk11`).

I have changed the `build.gradle` to:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

The version in the settings seems to be 11:

[image]

[image]

When I type `gradlew --version` it seems to be java 18. (The version I would like to use, if it were supported)

[image]

But even after multiple reloads, restarts, cleans and synchronizations the IDE still behaves as if I would use Java 8.

[image]

- Android Studio Version: Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2
- Gradle Version: 7.5.1

Comment: You can only use Java 11 language features but not the classes that were added in Java 9-11. `java.net.http.HttpClient` is a new class and thus you can't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750452/how-can-i-use-jdk-11-http-packages-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1) which explains that even the new versions of Android Studio simply don't support all features of Java 11.