# Can't import java.net.http into my Android project

Tags: java, android, kotlin

While trying to use GET request in my project, I stumbled a problem: I can't import java.net.http.

Here's part of my code (just an example, that I'm trying to reproduce):

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient
import java.net.http.HttpRequest
import java.net.http.HttpResponse


fun String.utf8(): String = URLEncoder.encode(this, "UTF-8")

fun main() {

    val params = mapOf("name" to "John Doe", "occupation" to "gardener")
    val urlParams = params.map {(k, v) -> "${(k.utf8())}=${v.utf8()}"}
        .joinToString("&")

    val client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
    val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://httpbin.org/get?${urlParams}"))
        .build();

    val response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    println(response.body())
}
```

Build output:

```
e: C:\Users\BJayD\AndroidStudioProjects\Viva_La_Resistance_Radio\VLR-Radio\app\src\main\java\com\example\viva_la_resistance_radio\Info.kt: (16, 17): Unresolved reference: http
e: C:\Users\BJayD\AndroidStudioProjects\Viva_La_Resistance_Radio\VLR-Radio\app\src\main\java\com\example\viva_la_resistance_radio\Info.kt: (17, 17): Unresolved reference: http
e: C:\Users\BJayD\AndroidStudioProjects\Viva_La_Resistance_Radio\VLR-Radio\app\src\main\java\com\example\viva_la_resistance_radio\Info.kt: (18, 17): Unresolved reference: http
e: C:\Users\BJayD\AndroidStudioProjects\Viva_La_Resistance_Radio\VLR-Radio\app\src\main\java\com\example\viva_la_resistance_radio\Info.kt: (29, 18): Unresolved reference: HttpClient
e: C:\Users\BJayD\AndroidStudioProjects\Viva_La_Resistance_Radio\VLR-Radio\app\src\main\java\com\example\viva_la_resistance_radio\Info.kt: (30, 19): Unresolved reference: HttpRequest
e: C:\Users\BJayD\AndroidStudioProjects\Viva_La_Resistance_Radio\VLR-Radio\app\src\main\java\com\example\viva_la_resistance_radio\Info.kt: (34, 41): Unresolved reference: HttpResponse
e: C:\Users\BJayD\AndroidStudioProjects\Viva_La_Resistance_Radio\VLR-Radio\app\src\main\java\com\example\viva_la_resistance_radio\Info.kt: (129, 23): Unresolved reference: HttpRequest
```

Here's my buld.gradle, since I found that the problem is usually with incompatibility between Java 8 and 11:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.viva_la_resistance_radio'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.viva_la_resistance_radio"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I updated Java already, changed settings, but nothing helps.
I think I've made a mistake somewhere else, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes you are trying to use are not part of the Android platform.  These are Java SE classes that were introduced in Java 11.

Unless the answers to [How can I use JDK 11 HTTP packages in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750452) are out of date, there are no ports of the `java.net.http.*` classes to Android (yet).

I recommend that you use one of the 3rd-party libraries listed in [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930).  The respective documentation will include examples for you to follow ... if that is what you need.